# django: managing data to show on templates

Tags: django, reporting, django-queryset

Is there a way to somehow pre-select data in the queryset before it's gone to templates? There is this 'project' models that connects to 'project_phase' and there are 'project_phase_history' records that keep track of all status changes.

I am building reports on top of this data and show all them projects on one page and want to display only project_phase_history that were submitted for the last few days OR one most recent.

I tried doing this in the view somehow like this:

```
projects_to_report_on = project.objects.filter(Q(current_phase__phase__id__in=[1,2,3,4]) & Q(role_sponsor__id = sponsor_id))
projects_to_report_on.current_phase.project_phase_history_set = projects_to_report_on.current_phase.project_phase_history.filter(...)
```

but this doesn't help, really - all data seems to jump into the template.

I ended up passing the date into the template and generating report as something like this:

```
{% for s in p.current_phase.project_phase_history_set.all %}
    {% if s.date_submitted >= status_start_date %}

    <tr>
    <td>{{ s.date_submitted }}</td>
    <td>{{ s.date_end_fact|default_if_none:"-" }}</td>
  </tr>
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
```

but it don't not have the flexibility I am looking for.

```
class project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1024,null=True,blank=True)
    current_phase = models.ForeignKey('project_phase', null=True, blank=True, related_name="current_phase")

class project_phase(models.Model):
    phase = models.ForeignKey('phases')
    project = models.ForeignKey('project')
    is_finished = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class project_phase_history(models.Model):
    project_phase = models.ForeignKey('project_phase')
    date_start_plan = models.DateField(null=True, blank=False)
    date_start_fact = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
projects_to_report_on.current_phase.project_phase_history_set = projects_to_report_on.current_phase.project_phase_history.filter(...)
```

You are setting the Manager of the reverse end of the relationship to a QuerySet. That does not work. Here's an example with blog and entry models:

```
>>> print(Entry.objects.all())
[<Entry: Today>, <Entry: Hello>]
>>> today = datetime.date.today()
>>> print(Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__lt=today).all())
[<Entry: Hello>]
>>> blog.entry_set = Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__lt=today())
>>> print(blog.entry_set.all())
[<Entry: Today>, <Entry: Hello>]
>>> blog.entry_set = Entry.objects.none()
>>> print(blog.entry_set.all())
[<Entry: Today>, <Entry: Hello>]
```

Because:

```
>>> blog.entry_set = Entry.objects.all()
>>> type(blog.entry_set)
<class 'django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager'>
```

This means `blog.entry_set` is still a Manager and calling `all` on a Manager will simply return all records. So don't do that. Pass the QuerySet to your template and use that:

```
history_set = projects_to_report_on.current_phase.project_phase_history_set.filter(...)
# add it to the context as 'history_set'

{% for s in history_set.all %}
```

Since you need to loop over both projects and the history of that project, I'd pass a dictionary to the template:

```
from django.utils.datastructures import SortedDict
# ...
project_map = SortedDict()
for project in projects_to_report_on:
    project_map[project] = history_query_set_goes_here
# ...
return render(request, template, {'project_map': project_map})
```

And then in your template:

```
{% for project, history_set in project_map.items %}
    <h2>{{ project }}</h2>
    <ol>
    {% for history in history_set.all %}
        <li>{{ history }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ol>
{% endfor %}
```

[SortedDict is documented on the Django wiki](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SortedDict). It maintains the order of insertion so if you retrieve the projects from the database in the correct order, they will display in the same order.

Comment: thanks for the comment. this would work if I was generating a report for a single project. since I'm pushing a lot of projects into the report and pass two (reports/statuses) collections into it, I would be able to bind them to each other in the template :( Unless I'm getting something wrong.